# Passing data from intent service to activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a broadcast receiver from which am calling intentservice.I want to send the data received in the intentservice to  a activity.String s=extras.getString("Notice").I want to send this received string to a new activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
   Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     dialogIntent.putExtra("value", extras.getString("Notice"));
     getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourIntentService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("YourStringKey", "yourString");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public YourIntentService() {
        super("YourIntentService");
    }

}
```

Try this. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: i want to send the data from intentservice to an activity.Not from broadcast receiver

Comment: Then add that flag like `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: Sorry if this is an ignorant question. Does this start a new activity or does the ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag just open the activity if it is already running?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

public  MyIntentService() {
    super(" MyIntentService");

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        String s=arg0.getExtras.getString("Notice")
        Intent i = new Intent(this, yourActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Notice",s);
        getApplication().startActivity(i);
}   

}
```