# How to pass String From IntentService To Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentservice

How to pass `String` From `IntentService` To `Activity`.

**MyService.java**

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

   String abc ="XYZ"; // pass this string to Activity class
}
```

Activity is same which is calling Service class.

Comment: Google is, you will find 1000s of answers already.

Comment: This was my first result. It would have taken you lesser effort than posting the question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928804/passing-data-from-intent-service-to-activity

Comment: you can use an intent/startActivity, or register a broadcast receiver in your activity, then use an Intent/sendBroadcast

Comment: @Rohit5k2 don't forget to flag as dupe if appropriate.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: I am the only one who flagged it.  :D

Comment: Sorry @Rohit5k2 The post appeared in triage and I thought the 'Possible duplicate' comment would have appeared if you had. As you were. :)

Comment: @Rohit5k2 : Actually My Activity is flickering When try Add code provided by u.. I want to Update same Activity from which i am Calling the service and also string is not getting passed

Comment: @rva: Please post your current code.

Comment: oki got the answer .....thanks all

Answer (score 0):

just simply goto inside onHandleIntent method and do some staffs like the code bellow

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){

 String abc ="XYZ"; // pass this string to Activity class
// Open a new activity called in my case Activity1
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
// Pass data to the new activity
intent.putExtra("message", abc);
//then finally start the activity
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: @Bejamin: Actually My Activity is flickering When try Add code provided by u.. I want to Update same Activity from which i am Calling the service and also string is not getting passed

Answer (score 0):

Use ResultReceiver class to send data from IntentService to Activity.
Please refer this link.
[How to get results from an IntentService back into an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334901/how-to-get-results-from-an-intentservice-back-into-an-activity)